# how to use regex in order to remove files with name as YEAR-MONTH-DAY

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

I want to delete the follwing files

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    51764 Jun 05 01:47 2010-06-03.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    42751 Jun 05 01:48 2015-06-21-under-test
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    34627 Jun 05 01:49 2013-03-22_deete
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    59828 Jun 05 01:51 2012-06-23-ol
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    33561 Jun 05 01:52 2011-06-22dont-touch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    36643 Jun 15 01:53 2011-07-02.3.434.3
```

so I create the follwing syntax

( in order to delete only the files that are named with "year-month-day" as 2014-06-02

```
find .  -regex  "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]*"
```

I also try

```
find .  -regex  "*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]*"
```

but files are not deleted

where I am wrong ?

Comment: Try `find .  -regex  ".*/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*"`

Comment: this doesn't delete the files

Comment: `find . -regex ".*/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*" -delete`?

Comment: the same , not delete the files

Comment: yes , the same ( not delete ) ,

Comment: @Wiktor , did you try it on your Linux machine/s ?  , we have Linux redhat version 7.2 , and this syntax not works well

Comment: Hm, try setting the regex type (if supported): `find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*" -delete`. Probably the interval quantifier is the culprit.

Comment: find . -regextype sed -regex ".*/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}.*"  -print , this not print anything -:(

Comment: It works in Ubuntu, sorry, that is all I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close :

Instead of :

```
find .  -name  "*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9]-[0-9]*" -delete
```

use :

```
find .  -name  "*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*" -delete
```

Comment: the syntax should be find .  -name  "*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*" -delete

Comment: Added, but I assume OP know how to do this

Comment: if I want to use the "-regex" , then how to do it , the command - find .  -regex  "*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]*"   , not works

Comment: If you want to use regex, then why it's not explained in your original post ? I offer a working solution